# Sony ZV-1: USB Power Supply setting does nothing?

Tags: camera-settings, sony, usb, power-supply, power

I recently purchased a ZV-1 and have been coming up to speed with all its settings. One thing I haven't managed to figure out, is what the "USB Power Supply" ON/OFF toggle does.

This should theoretically control if the camera is able to receive power (but not charge its battery) while turned ON through its micro USB port (it should charge the battery through this port when OFF regardless of setting).

Unfortunately, I have never gotten the OFF setting to work. Regardless of the setting selection, the camera always takes power through the USB port, independent of being in Movie mode, Mass storage, USB streaming mode, or preview. After every setting change I restarted the camera and replugged the cable, and tried both with a power bank and computer, using the original micro USB cable. With the setting set to OFF, the camera still draws power through USB while powered ON...

This behavior suits me fine, but it bugs me not knowing what a setting does, or it possibly being bugged in the software.

Can anybody explain how/when the "USB Power Supply" setting comes into play? Is the behavior I observed normal? In what circumstance should the active camera NOT draw any power through USB with the setting set to OFF?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 192 of the user manual says:

> “During USB streaming, power is supplied to the camera from the
> computer. If you want to consume as little computer power as possible,
> set [USB Power Supply] to [Off].”

[image]